# Creating a transaction through DataSource.getTransaction(def) does not set the currentTransactionStatus to it

Tags: java, spring, transactions

We have an application with three databases. Two of them are only very seldomly updated. We tried JPA to create transactions around it and it worked for the databases, but grails then did not work on different places (gsp related I am told). This was tried quite a while ago (and not by me).

Due to delivery pressure we needed a solution that at least works for us, so I created a new aspect for the methods changing data in multiple databases. I got this to work, it is a fairly simple approach.

In the aspect we request to start a transaction for each data source, by calling getTransaction(TransactionDefinition def) with the propagation set to REQUIRES_NEW. We then proceed and finally rollback or commit depending on the outcome of the call.

However, one test flow failed. This is the scenario where the code requests a rollback by calling TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly(). Of the three TransactionStatusses obtained initially, none actually returns isRollbackOnly() with true. However calling TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransationStatus().isRollbackOnly() does return true. So this seems to point to a different transaction status.

I have not been able to figure out how to make this work, other than checking this additional status. I could not find a way to change the currentTransactionStatus to the one of created TransactionStatus. Looking at the TransactionTemplate implementation, I seem to do things correctly (it also just calls getTransaction() on the datasource).

The code calling the decorated method has specified @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED), so I expected no currentTransactionStatus, but one is there.
However, if it is not there the proxied code will not be able to request a rollback the standard way, which I want to be able to fix.

So the question is, how to start a transaction correctly from an Aspect so that the currentTransactionStatus is set correctly or how to set the currentTransactionStatus to what I think is the correct one.

Regards,
Wim Veldhuis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

@Transactional leads to a different code path, where eventually TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction is invoked. This method will set up the current transaction correctly.

So in order to make my approach working, I needed to derive from TransactionAspectSupport, do a number of cast operations so I could get to the correct values for the invokeWithinTransaction call, and within the guarded function block use getTransaction(def) to obtain txns for the OTHER databases. I have choose the most important database to be the one used for invoke...

To make it work I had also to provide a TransactionAttributeSource, that returned my default transaction attributes.That one is stored into the TransactionAspectSupport base class during initialization.

```
    @Around("@annotation(framework.db.MultiDbTransactional)")
public Object multiDbTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

    // Get class and method, needed for parent invocation. We need to cast to the actual
    // implementation
    MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint mipJoinPoint = (MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint) proceedingJoinPoint;
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) mipJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Class<?> clazz = mipJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();

    return invokeWithinTransaction(method, clazz, new InvocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object proceedWithInvocation() throws Throwable {

            // This class will create the other transactions, not of interest here.
            MultiDbTxnContext ctx = new MultiDbTxnContext();
            ctx.startTransactions();

            /*
             * We have started the transactions, so do the job. We mimic DEFAULT spring behavior
             * regarding exceptions, so runtime exceptions roll back, the rest commits.
             */
            try {
                Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
                ctx.finishTransactions();
                return result;
            } catch (Error | RuntimeException re) {
                ctx.rollbackTransactions();
                throw re;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                ctx.commitTransactions();
                throw t;
            }
        }
    });

}
```